# flake8 linter in Sublime Text stopped showing F841 assigned but never used warning

Tags: sublimetext3, flake8

As the title states, in Sublime Text 3.1.1 with flake8 3.5 for the following python code:

```
x = 1
y = 2
print(y)
```

I would expect x = 1 to be highlighted with F841 "local variable
name is assigned to but never used" warning but it doesn't show up neither in the code nor in the linter gutter. There is nothing referencing code F841 in any of the linter settings files (no exclusions). Apart from this, linter appears to be working fine. I can obviously code without this, but it'd be nice to know what goes on here, so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If this is in the module scope then `flake8` can't know if you *meant* to export `x` to other modules, in which case it should not warn about this.

Comment: @phoenix thanks, made me go look at namespaces and scopes. Makes all the sense.